# How to send a notification to Android app "A" from app "B"? The firebase project connections of these two apps are different

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have two Android applications; for the time being, let them be "A" and "B", and they both connect up with different firebase projects. My main objective here is to send notifications to app "B" whenever any changes are being made in the firestore of app "A" so that the user of app "B" would check up on the changes that are being made and evaluate them accordingly.

I have an idea of how Firebase Cloud Messaging works, and I am successfully sending and receiving notifications between different android devices that use the same android application. But when sending notifications between two different applications present on two different devices, I have no idea what shall I do, and I am currently stuck here for the past week. So I will be grateful to those who can help me get an idea of how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple apps to one Firebase project:

You can add app B to Firebase project A and use project A for FCM messages.

Look here :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Comment: Hey Lluis Felisart, thanks for responding; after adding them to the same project, should I pass the server key of app "B" in the interface of app "A", which has been written to send notification from "A."

Comment: You should the same server key to send messages from both apps, the server key of the shared firebase project

Comment: Hey, thanks, @LluisFelisart, it helped in my project.